# \PhpOffice\PhpWord issue converting HTML to DOCX

Tags: laravel, docx, phpoffice

Thank you in advance

i want to convert HTML into DOCX so i used \PhpOffice\PhpWord library in laravel

The code for the same is as below

```
$html = "<html><body><h1>HELLO DEMO</h1></body></html>";
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);
$phpWord->save(public_path('temp/demo.docx'), 'Word2007');
```

instead of saving the docx, it is showing the HTML on the webpage.
I want to save into a folder
is there anything missed by me, i used this in laravel so `require_once "vendor/autoload.php";` might not be required?

Answer (score 0):

You need the

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

also add and change

```
$path = public_path('temp/demo.docx');
$phpWord->save($path, 'Word2007');
```